# Displaying column in tableView

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, javafx, collections

I'm trying to map and display data from tables between which there is a one-to-one relationship using `TableView` from JavaFX 8 and hibernate.

Tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLUB")
public class Club implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CLUB_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int clubId;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "CITY", length = 50)
    private String city;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "club", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Trainer trainer;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRAINER")
public class Trainer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LICENCE_NR", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int licenceNr;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SURNAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String surname;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Club club;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

`ClubController` class with `TableView`:

```
public class ClubController implements Initializable {

    ...

    @FXML
    private TableView<Club> clubTableView;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Club, String> nameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Club, String> cityColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Club, Integer> trainerColumn;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Club, String>("name"));
        cityColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Club, String>("city"));
        trainerColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Club, Integer>, ObservableValue<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Integer> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Club, Integer> param) {
                return new SimpleIntegerProperty(param.getValue().getTrainer().getLicenceNr()).asObject();
            }
        });
        clubTableView.setItems(getClub());
    }

    private ObservableList<Club> getClub() {
        ObservableList<Club> clubList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.config().openSession();
        List<Club> cList = session.createCriteria(Club.class).list();
        clubList.addAll(cList);
        session.close();
        return clubList;
    }

    ...
}
```

First two columns work correctly, but in the `trainerColumn` I have NPE. How to fix it?

Comment: The constructor of `SimpleIntegerProperty` takes a primitive `int` value as parameter. This means that the property ***cannot*** contain a `null` value. (A NPE would be possible though. So either the description of the issue is misleading or you did not post the code required to reproduce the issue...

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's NPE, not null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trainer` field in the `CLUB` entity is lazy loaded:

```
...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "club", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Trainer trainer;
...
```

... which can only be read while the session that created the entity is opened.

In the `ClubController`, you opened and closed the session, without explicitly loading the `trainer` details from the DB:

```
    private ObservableList<Club> getClub() {
        ObservableList<Club> clubList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        // SESSION OPENED
        Session session = HibernateUtil.config().openSession();

        // CLUB ENTITIES LOADED WITH LAZY TRAINERS
        List<Club> cList = session.createCriteria(Club.class).list();
        clubList.addAll(cList);

        //SESSION CLOSED
        session.close();

        return clubList;
    }
```

So either make the `trainer` field in the `CLUB` entity to be eager loaded:

```
...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "club", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Trainer trainer;
...
```

Or explicitly load the `trainer` when querying the DB - with something as simple as:

```
...
        // SESSION OPENED
        Session session = HibernateUtil.config().openSession();

        // CLUB ENTITIES LOADED WITH LAZY TRAINERS
        List<Club> cList = session.createCriteria(Club.class).list();

        // EXPLICITLY LOAD ALL TRAINERS FROM DB
        cList.stream().peek(club -> club.getTrainer().getLicenceNr())
        clubList.addAll(cList);

        //SESSION CLOSED
        session.close();
...
```

Although, I advice against this last one, since is a bit dirty and less performing (many extra round trips to the DB, 
instead of a single join query for all one-to-one record query if eager); but still available.

Comment: I tried both solutions. I get still the NullPointerException.

Comment: Before closing your session invoke `cList.stream().peek(club -> System.out.println(club.getTrainer().getLicenceNr()))` and make sure that all trainers are loaded from the DB. If you get a NPE there, then you have **another** problem related to loading the `trainers` from the DB and nothing to do withe the current one; for which a deeper debugging would be needed (i.e. most likely some clubs do not have a `trainer` associated in your DB)

Comment: Okay, thanks for tips. I do the same operations with other tables and there it works correctly, so it has to be a problem with relation between `Trainer` and `Club`. I will try to find a mistake.